# Scraping a Table using BeautifulSoup in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print a table of baby's names given in list format using Beautifulsoup.

[google-python-exercises/google-python-exercises/babynames/baby1990.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtNEV.jpg)
(HTML page is a screenshot of actual URL)

After fetching the table using urllib.request and parsing it with BeautifulSoup, I was able to print the data inside every row of the table but I'm getting the wrong output.

here is my code:

```
right_table = soup.find('table',attrs = {"summary" : "Popularity for top 1000"})
table_rows = right_table.find_all('tr') 

for tr in table_rows:
td = tr.find_all('td')
row = [i.text for i in td]
print(row)
```

It is supposed to print 1 list containing all the data in the rows, However, I get a number of lists with every new list starting with one less record in it

Kind of like this:

```
['997', 'Eliezer', 'Asha', '998', 'Jory', 'Jada', '999', 'Misael', 'Leila', '1000', 'Tate', 'Peggy', 'Note: Rank 1 is the most popular,\nrank 2 is the next most popular, and so forth. \n']
['998', 'Jory', 'Jada', '999', 'Misael', 'Leila', '1000', 'Tate', 'Peggy', 'Note: Rank 1 is the most popular,\nrank 2 is the next most popular, and so forth. \n']
['999', 'Misael', 'Leila', '1000', 'Tate', 'Peggy', 'Note: Rank 1 is the most popular,\nrank 2 is the next most popular, and so forth. \n']
['1000', 'Tate', 'Peggy', 'Note: Rank 1 is the most popular,\nrank 2 is the next most popular, and so forth. \n']
['Note: Rank 1 is the most popular,\nrank 2 is the next most popular, and so forth. \n']
```

How to print only one list?

Answer (score 2):

I would try and use pandas and index into results list of tables to get the table you want

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('yourURL')

print(tables[1]) # for example; change index as required
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is creating your row list, then prints it, and then it goes into the next iteration, where it creates a row list (overwriting your previous), then printing it, etc etc etc.

Not sure why you’d want all the rows into one list, but To have one final list, you’ll need to append each row list into a final list at each iteration.

Do you actually mean you want a list of your rows list?

```
right_table = soup.find('table',attrs = {"summary" : "Popularity for top 1000"})
table_rows = right_table.find_all('tr') 


result_list = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    result_list = result_list + row


print(result_list)
```

If you really meant a list of your rows, then use this one:

```
right_table = soup.find('table',attrs = {"summary" : "Popularity for top 1000"})
table_rows = right_table.find_all('tr') 


result_list = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    result_list.append(row)


print(result_list)
```

But honestly, I’d use pandas and .read_html() as QHarr suggests.

```
right_table = soup.find('table',attrs = {"summary" : "Popularity for top 1000"})
table_rows = right_table.find_all('tr') 


result_list = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    for data in td:
        print (td.text)
```

Comment: I mean a list which just prints every cell in the table once, however it keeps iterating for the number of items present in the table. I don't understand what to do.

Comment: If you just want ever cell printed, then print each cell element.

Comment: To be true I'm not able to explain myself in a proper way. Maybe because I'm new at this , let me try again. And I'm sorry if I'm causing you any trouble. You were right it is printing itself in a loop. Do you know how it is that I can break away from the loop and print it out only for one time . The very first time. I don't want other iterations to print themselves.

Comment: Oh no, no trouble at all. To get the data, you’ll have 3 options. 1) you have to iterate with a for loop (no way around that). 2) use QHarr method of using pandas read_html (which uses beautifulsoup under the hood to iterate...but we don’t see it), to get all the data on one go, and print that. 3) it’s possible there is a json response that could read that response and get the data on one go. The 3rd option though I could only know if you share the url, and specify what data you’re trying to scrape.